# Set sessions before datagrid's hyperlink OnClick

Tags: asp.net, session, datagrid

I have a datagrid on my website, and one of column is hyperlink column. i need to set some sessions before i click on the hyperlink. but i can't set the sessions on client-side. How can i do it?

Note: i cannot use the button column, browsers "open in new window", "open in new tab" properties doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just use querystring? or post some code so you might get help.

Comment: i dont want to show the code in adress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinkButton`. This control generates a postback to server as any button. On the button handler, set the session variables you need and do a `Response.Redirect()` after that.

If you need to open the link in a new window. Use this instead of `Response.Redirect()`

**ASPX**

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"     
    OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Open</asp:LinkButton>
```

**CS**

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyVar1"] = "SomeValue";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "OPEN_NEW_WINDOW",  
      "window.open('page.aspx','_blank')", true);
}
```

Comment: can i use "open in new tab" or "open in new window" properties with LinkButton?

Comment: @erdincozdemir: LinkButton click handler

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to set session variable from client you can still do it, but you will have to make an AJAX call to the server for that.

Comment: Is this answer the question??

Comment: yeah i know, but i dont wanna use the ajax on my page.

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: Yes. The question was "how to set session vars before click" and this is one of the possible answers.